# SQLAlchemy errors in virtualenv

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-2.7, virtualenv

I'm trying to run a python script on a computer where I do not have root privileges.  To do so, I've set up a `virtualenv` using Python 2.7, then I add the two packages that I need Parallel Python and SQLAlchemy.  When I run the script I get this error:

```
(virtPython)thaddeus:recipes ab940$ python2.7 matchIngsParallel.py 
Starting pp with 8 workers
Reading ingredients into dictionary
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matchIngsParallel.py", line 65, in <module>
    for synonym, parentIng in session.query(IngSyn.synonym, IngSyn.parentIng): 
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2227, in     __iter__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2242, in     _execute_and_instances
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1449, in execute
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1584, in _execute_clauseelement
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1698, in _execute_context
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1691, in _execute_context
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 331, in do_execute
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: ingSyns u'SELECT     "ingSyns".synonym AS "ingSyns_synonym", "ingSyns"."parentIng" AS "ingSyns_parentIng" \nFROM     "ingSyns"' ()
```

It seems as though everything is being imported correctly but the database is not being accessed properly.

The script is as follows:

```
from assignDB import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import pp, sys

ppservers = ()

job_server = pp.Server(ppservers=ppservers)

print "Starting pp with", job_server.get_ncpus(), "workers"

print "Reading ingredients into dictionary"
ingreds = {}
for synonym, parentIng in session.query(IngSyn.synonym, IngSyn.parentIng): 
    ingreds[synonym] = parentIng
print "Finished reading ingredients"
```

(This code is shortened, but includes the place where the error occurs)

`assignDB` looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, create_engine, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite import DATETIME, REAL

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///recDB.db')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()
```

followed by the class definitions.

I've tried this script on other computers (where I have root access, however), including in other virtualenvs, and it works fine.  I'm very confused about what could be going wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Your script can access the database alright, but there seem to be no tables in it. I suppose you copied the script from another machine, did you also copy the SQLite database file `recDB.db`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm accessing a dropbox folder, so it's identical on all machines.  I'm thinking there is some problem with the way in which the virtualenv calls the imports, particularly of `assignDB`?  And wouldn't it pass an error if it couldn't find the database when it creates the engine?

Comment: If the SQLite driver can't find the file, it creates it, so you wouldn't see an error there. `'sqlite:///recDB.db'` is a path relative to your current working directory, I suppose you start your python shell after `cd`ing to the dropbox folder? Your `assignDB` import succeeds, otherwise there would be an `ImportError` on the first line of your script. What makes you think it's an import problem?